# How could I click a button with no name,ID or value on vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, vba

I know this might be easy but I am having a hard time getting a button to click has no value, name or type please help me.this is all there is for the button.

```
                     <button class="white-button" type="submit">

                    Submit

                </button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: i see that you have a class in button, you can make use of it

Comment: would that be how i could get it to click?

Comment: using `$('.white-button').click()`

Comment: yes, see the demo in the answer,

Comment: the thing is that i dont know java i right in the i am using vba .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  class name in button.

JS

```
$(function(){
  $('.white-button').on('click',function(){
   alert('hi');
  })
})
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/jasea0jr/)